# What is the difference between "return new A()" and "return a = new A()"

Tags: java

I saw in many libraries, when returning some result, is used return `a = new A()` (e.g. `return entrySet = new EntrySet()`) instead of returning just `new EntrySet()`, what's the difference ?

Comment: What scope does `a` or `newEntrySet` have?

Comment: If `entrySet` is a local then there is no difference. If `entrySet` is a class member then there is a clear difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return a = new A()` returns the value of the assignment of `new A()` to `a`. The value of an assignment is the value that was assigned.

So they both return the exact same value.

*However* `return a = new A()` *also* assigns the value to `a`. If `a` is a local variable, then this is an assignment that won't have any effect and should be removed. If `a` is a field, then this might be used to *remember* the last returned value for some reason.

In the latter case it will work, but I'd say that it's bad style (that line does more than 1 thing. Actually it does 3 things) and I'd rewrite it like this:

```
a = new A();
return a;
```

Answer (score 6):

The latter assigns a value to `a` before returning.

If `a` is local variable, it's almost certainly irrelevant. If `a` is an instance (or static) variable this will have a visible side-effect. It's sometimes used for sort of lazy initialization, e.g.

```
private String foo;

public String getFoo()
{
    if (foo != null)
    {
        return foo;
    }
    return foo = computeFoo();
}

private String computeFoo() { .. }
```

Comment: The question is about Java, not C#.

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can answer questions with the wrong language, and still manage to end up with most votes :-)

Comment: @JBNizet: Whoops, fixed thanks. Exactly the same principle of course :)

Comment: @aioobe: that's what a conspirator would say ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First things that comes to mind is "so you can inspect the return value inside the called method before  actually exiting it". Honestly I've always thought both ways were equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a local variable, there's no difference at all (after even a trivial amount of optimization). It's just a pointless assignment. But if it's an assignment to a field, that's just shorthand for:

```
this.a = new A();
return this.a;
```

Some people like to do it one way, some the other.

Answer (score 0):

The result of an assignment is the value being assigned.

So in

```
 private int x;

 public int setX(int x) { return this.x = x; }
```

the `setX` method assigns its argument to `this.x` and returns the new value of `this.x`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the value is first assigned to a variable and then returned. If it's a local variable, this doesn't really have any effect as it will be out of scope as soon as the method returns. It would matter if it's an instance variable.

But I've never seen this kind of thing, and would consider it a rather dubious practice. What exactly tare the "mnay libraries" you've seen it being used in?

**Update**: I've just seen it being used in `java.util.HashMap`, apparently for lazy initialization of the `entrySet` field. I guess it makes sense for that kind of thing.

Comment: for example EnumMap in Java core libraries, there's a transient field entrySet which is updated everytime the entrySet is returned.

Comment: @Bax: Actually, that's the same thing, lazy initialization. If the field is not null, its content is returned directly.